# How to prevent multiple iterations of the same CFQuery in a CFLoop and format into a matrix

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have researched this quite a bit and haven't found quite the answer I'm looking for.  I was able to get to this point with a little help but now am stuck at yet another hurdle.

I would like to be able to display all UNIQUE company names down the leftmost column, then a 'tally' of the number of tests of each type conducted within a specific month.  I have commented out a bit of my code that, although it works, doesn't account for when the number of a particular test equals zero (no records in db that fit the conditions), which is needed for, if nothing else, to make sure the other tests don't get their 'tallies' mixed up.  My code will probably help to elaborate:

```
<cfset s = structNew()>
<cfquery datasource="test" name="qry">
    SELECT company, test_type, count(test_type) as counter 
    FROM donor_log
    GROUP BY company, test_type
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="qry">
    <cfset s[qry.company][qry.test_type] = qry.counter>
</cfloop>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>UA</th>
        <th>BA</th>
        <th>Hair</th>
        <th>Blood</th>
    </tr>
    <cfoutput>
    <cfloop collection="#s#" item="i">
        <tr>
            <td>#i#</td>
            <cfloop collection="#s[i]#" item="j">
                <cfquery dbtype="query" name="ua">
                    SELECT DISTINCT company 
                    FROM qry 
                    WHERE company='#i#' 
                      AND test_type='UA'
                </cfquery>
                <cfdump var="#ua#"> 
                <!---
                <cfif val(s[i][j]) EQ 0>
                    <td>0</td>
                <cfelse>  
                    <td>#s[i][j]#</td>
                </cfif>
                 --->
            </cfloop>  
        </tr>
    </cfloop> 
    </cfoutput>
```

The commented section doesn't print '0' to the screen when the `structKey` value equals 0 and presently, if a company has, say, 0 UA's but 2 BA's, the cell under UA says 2 and BA has nothing.  So there is something wrong with my `<cfif>` statement too, but I'm not sure what.  Please understand I am just starting to learn ColdFusion and most of what I have on this particular page is from another kind soul's post on a different forum.  I look forward to your replies and input, thanks in advance!

PS quick edit: When I use the `<cfdump>` as above, the output is 1 whole query for a company with 1 such record `company="#i#" AND test_type="UA"`, 2 queries for a company with 2 such records, 3 queries if 3 matching records, and so on.  Ultimately would like this query to run just ONCE for each company `"#i#"` and then pull the `s[i][j].recordcount` (wherever it doesn't equal 0) so I can then compare that against a different table (a fee schedule) and generate a total amount to bill each company based on number of tests performed, if that makes sense, but I need to cross this bridge first.

Comment: This sounds like a pivot report. You might look into using a sql `pivot` instead of building this in CF. IF your database supports it. 1) What db type and version are you using? 2) How many test types are there? Are there a *fixed* number of types? (BTW, be sure to always include db type and version with query questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I'd just reorganize the query like something below

```
<cfquery datasource="test" name="qry">
SELECT company, SUM(CASE WHEN test_type = 'UA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS UACount
, SUM(CASE WHEN test_type = 'BA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BACount
, SUM(CASE WHEN test_type = 'Hair' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HairCount
, SUM(CASE WHEN test_type = 'Blood' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BloodCount
FROM donor_log
GROUP BY company
</cfquery>
```

and then output

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>UA</th>
    <th>BA</th>
    <th>Hair</th>
    <th>Blood</th>
</tr>
<cfoutput query="qry">
 <tr>
  <td>#qry.Company#</td>
  <td>#qry.UACount#</td>
  <td>#qry.BHCount#</td>
  <td>#qry.HairCount#</td>
  <td>#qry.BloodCount#</td>
 </tr>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: I was thinking something along the same lines.  I edited your answer to match the output variables with the names you gave in the query.

Comment: +1. Yep, I was going to suggest that next :) But I was not sure if the number of test types was fixed. If so, a `case` will work quite nicely - and unlike `pivot` - the syntax is compatible with most databases.

Comment: Apparently my edits went to the bit-bucket.  Guess I don't have enough rep or something???  :/

Comment: @Miguel-F I can't approve your edits, so I just fixed it myself.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for updating your answer.

Comment: Matt, thank you, I was really stumped, looks like I was overthinking it  :)  Kudos to you!  I was actually unaware you could do that much w/ SQL as opposed to using CF but I should have mentioned I'm relatively new to SQL as well. @Miguel-F Thank you for the input regardless, I appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks to you as well Leigh and duly noted re: the DB engine, I'll remember that next post :)

Comment: @BrandonG, since you are new to sql, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.  Miguel-F, whatever happened to your edits was not due to lack of rep.  Yours is justifiably higher than mine and I've done it.

Comment: Rudy Limeback wrote a great SQL book called Simply SQL.  Very easy to read and understand.  Not to mention he lurks around the CF community so if you wanted to "hook a brother up", check it out.

Comment: @DanBracuk - It was due to reputation level. Until you reach a certain number of points (I do not remember how many) edits to other answers are placed in a queue for [review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/), and three out of five members must vote to approve or reject it. The reviewers are not necessarily CF people, just whoever happens reviews it first.